A JavaScript error occured in the main process: Unexpected end of JSON input
I’m reaching out for advice on resolving the issue shown in the attached image regarding the error message:
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Unexpected end of JSON input

The error popped up unexpectedly when I tried running my JupyterLab notebook. I followed the advice to delete all cached files located at C:\Users<YourUsername>\AppData\Roaming\jupyterlab-desktop\Cache as suggested by ChatGPT, but unfortunately, it didn’t resolve the issue.
Next, I uninstalled and reinstalled JupyterLab Desktop from the official GitHub page (https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop), but the problem persists. The same error appears whenever I attempt to open any JupyterLab notebook or even the JupyterLab desktop app itself.
Could you please guide me on how to resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Problem's solved after deleting the entire folder at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\jupyterlab-desktop and reinstalled the application. However, I still don't understand why this error occurred so suddenly. Thanks.
